# Python 3 - Getting key error from list of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

This seemingly simple piece of code is giving me a key error. What have I done wrong?

```
a = [{"a": [1,2,3]}, {"b": [1,2,3]}, {"c": [1,2,3]}]
b = [dict["a"] for dict in a]
print(b)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/mydir/myscript.py", line 2, in <module>
    b = [dict["a"] for dict in a]
  File "G:/mydir/myscript.py", line 2, in <listcomp>
    b = [dict["a"] for dict in a]
KeyError: 'a'
```

Comment: Not all dicts have an `"a"` key...

Comment: 1. Don't name variables after built-ins 2. dictionaries have a `get` method, look into that

Comment: explain why a down vote as per SO community guidelines - explanation, code and traceback...

Comment: I didn't doenvote but I don't see an explanation... I see three dicts with a single unique key and you trying to get the same key from all of them. How can we help without knowing what you're trying to do? Do you expect to get something if the key is not there? What is your question? What is your expected output?

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but this is a very low effort question, where the mistake should be clear after looking at the problem for max 5min. [This](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is a good read for everybody that posts these kinds of questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the three dictionaries in `a` only the first one contains the key `"a"`.
You can use the method `.get(<key>)` which will return `None` if the key is not in the dictionary.

For example

```
a = [{"a": [1,2,3]}, {"b": [1,2,3]}, {"c": [1,2,3]}]
b = [dict.get("a") for dict in a]
print(b) # output: [[1,2,3], None, None]
```

I would also suggest not using the name `dict` since that is used by Python to interact with the dictionaries class, so perhaps you can consider changing it to something like

```
a = [{"a": [1,2,3]}, {"b": [1,2,3]}, {"c": [1,2,3]}]
b = [d.get("a") for d in a]
print(b) # output: [[1,2,3], None, None]
```

If you wanted your code to work the way you had set up the problem, you would need to make sure that every dictionary in `a` has the key `"a"`, i.e. something like

```
a = [{"a": [1,2,3]}, {"a": [1,2,3]}, {"a": [1,2,3]}]
```